# apache configuration preventing wordpress front page on ec2 linux instance

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I was having a problem where I was getting "not found" error messages from apache on pages in my wordpress site. I have the correct .htaccess file.

I changed the "AllowOverride" setting in httpd.conf as described here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/url-rewriting-not-working

Now my "interior" pages show just fine (e.g., domain.com/page), but not the front page (a static page in wordpress). All I get is the header and footer, but none of the home page content.

Could this be an apache configuration problem beyond what I changed in allowoverride? I'm running an ec2 linux instance.

Comment: I don't think this is an Apache/.htaccess problem. It looks rather like some Wordpress problem.

Comment: Other than making sure the static front page is properly assigned, what wordpress problem could it be?

Comment: You might be right, actually. When I assigned a different page to be the static front page, it worked just fine. Now to figure out what is causing the problem!

Comment: When your problem is solved, you might either delete the question or add an answer yourself, explaining the solution, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

@Olaf-Dietsche was correct - it was a wordpress problem, which I confirmed by assigning a different page as the static front page. Then I successfully debugged the page in question that I wanted to be the static front page.